# fisrt 5th iterations of a sequence of functions: integro-differential equations

Tags: equation-solving, difference-equations, integral-equations

Please I am struggling to compute with mathematica the first 5th iterations of the sequence of functions $u[n,t]$ satisfying the integro-differential equation
[image]

Please help me with the code.

Patrick

Comment: `u0[x_] := -x/6 + 2/3; u1[x_] := u0[x] + Integrate[(t-1) (2-x) (u0''[t] - u0[t]^3 + u0[t] u0'[t]), {t, 1, x}] + Integrate[(x-1) (2-t) (u0''[t] - u0[t]^3 + u0[t] u0'[t]), {t, x, 2}]; u1[x]` shows me u1. Then `u2[x_] := u1[x] + Integrate[(t-1) (2-x) (u1''[t] - u1[t]^3 + u1[t] u1'[t]), {t, 1, x}] + Integrate[(x - 1) (2 - t) (u1''[t] - u1[t]^3 + u1[t] u1'[t]), {t, x, 2}]; u2[x]` shows me u2. Repeat for u3, u4, ...

Comment: @Bill if that is an answer, why don't you post it as such?

Comment: @Patrick Here its considered helpful to show your own efforts and share your code in a **[well formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) instead of images** or links to external files, so we can quickly **Copy&Paste** your code, test it, and  see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question accordingly. This [question in Meta](https://wolfr.am/v57TjMS9) could be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps  little bit more comfortable than Bill's answer:

```
igl[x_, u_(* function*)] :=u[x] + 
Integrate[(t - 1) (2 - x) (u''[t] - u[t]^3 + u[t] u'[t]), {t,1, x}] +
Integrate[(x - 1) (2 - t) (u''[t] - u[t]^3 + u[t] u'[t]), {t, x, 2}]
u0[x_] := -x/6 + 2/3
u1[x_] :=igl[x,u0 ]  
u2[x_] :=igl[x,u1]  
(* ... *)
```

A much nicer program could be somthing like

```
NestList[Evaluate[igl[x, #&]]  , u0 , 1]
```

but it doesn't run...

Comment: How about something along the lines of `u[0][x_]:=-x/6 + 2/3` and `u[n_][x_]:=igl[x,u[n-1]]` (untested)?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: It works, thank you! But I'm still wondering why `NestList[ igl[x, # & ]  , -x/6 + 2/3   , 1]` doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you very much guys for your help. It is working :)